# DC JS Limiting brushing height

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

Is there a way to limit the brushing height - say 50% of y axis (only from Y axis 0 - 250, brushing should work) ? [Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e5gC2/806/)

JS Code:

```
var hitslineChart = dc.barChart("#chart-line-hitsperday"); 

            var data = [
        {date: "12/27/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 190, http_302: 100},
        {date: "12/28/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 10, http_302: 100},
        {date: "12/29/2012", http_404: 1, http_200: 300, http_302: 200},
        {date: "12/30/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
        {date: "12/31/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
        {date: "01/01/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
        {date: "01/02/2013", http_404: 1, http_200: 10, http_302: 1},
        {date: "01/03/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
        {date: "01/04/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
        {date: "01/05/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
        {date: "01/06/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 200, http_302: 1},
        {date: "01/07/2013", http_404: 1, http_200: 200, http_302: 100}
        ];

            var ndx = crossfilter(data); 
            var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y").parse;
            data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = Date.parse(d.date);
        d.total= d.http_404+d.http_200+d.http_302;
        });
            var dateDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.date;});
            var hits = dateDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.total;});
            var minDate = dateDim.bottom(1)[0].date;
            var maxDate = dateDim.top(1)[0].date;

        hitslineChart.width(500)
                   .height(200)
                     .dimension(dateDim)
                     .group(hits)
                     .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate,maxDate]));                                         
            dc.renderAll();
```

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your example uses dc.js 1.7.0, I'm going to answer for dc.js 2.0, since it's a lot newer and a few APIs have changed.

The technique is to override the functions from the [coordinateGridMixin](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.coordinateGridMixin.html) which size the brush. This gets a little hairy, but it's possible.

It turns out we'll have to override three undocumented functions which render the brush, [renderBrush](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/9c5bc3d49540f51bccfdd746fdf91f2dcd20446d/src/coordinate-grid-mixin.js#L971), [setBrushY](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/9c5bc3d49540f51bccfdd746fdf91f2dcd20446d/src/coordinate-grid-mixin.js#L994), and (unfortunately) [resizeHandlePath](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/9c5bc3d49540f51bccfdd746fdf91f2dcd20446d/src/coordinate-grid-mixin.js#L1058).

The reason this gets hairy is that we really want to override [brushHeight](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/9c5bc3d49540f51bccfdd746fdf91f2dcd20446d/src/coordinate-grid-mixin.js#L967), but that one is a private function.

We'll define our own like this:

```
function height_over_2() {
  return (hitslineChart._xAxisY() - hitslineChart.margins().top)/2;
}
```

For renderBrush, we need to shift the brush down by `height_over_2()`. We'll pass through the call first, then modify the transform:

```
dc.override(hitslineChart, 'renderBrush', function(g) { 
   hitslineChart._renderBrush(g);
   var gBrush = hitslineChart.select('g.brush')
         .attr('transform', 'translate(' + hitslineChart.margins().left + ',' + (hitslineChart.margins().top + height_over_2()) + ')')
});
```

setBrushY we'll replace entirely (we could just assign to it, but we'll use `dc.override` for consistency):

```
dc.override(hitslineChart, 'setBrushY', function(gBrush) {
  gBrush.selectAll('rect')
      .attr('height', height_over_2());
  gBrush.selectAll('.resize path')
      .attr('d', hitslineChart.resizeHandlePath);  
 });
```

Finally, resizeHandlePath also uses the height, and here we (ugh) have to copy a big chunk of code out of dc.js, which was itself copied from the crossfilter demo:

```
dc.override(hitslineChart, 'resizeHandlePath', function (d) {
    var e = +(d === 'e'), x = e ? 1 : -1, y = height_over_2() / 3;
    return 'M' + (0.5 * x) + ',' + y +
        'A6,6 0 0 ' + e + ' ' + (6.5 * x) + ',' + (y + 6) +
        'V' + (2 * y - 6) +
        'A6,6 0 0 ' + e + ' ' + (0.5 * x) + ',' + (2 * y) +
        'Z' +
        'M' + (2.5 * x) + ',' + (y + 8) +
        'V' + (2 * y - 8) +
        'M' + (4.5 * x) + ',' + (y + 8) +
        'V' + (2 * y - 8);
});
```

[image: short brush]

Fork of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/anz9gfy0/13/

Comment: I'd consider making `brushHeight` overrideable in dc.js, but frankly this request has never come up before.

Comment: Thanks Gordon!! Please consider adding brushHeight overridable in dc.js as the data point tool tips don't appear when we hover on the charts, which are pretty much useful.

Comment: Oh is that the use case? I shoulda asked. I recently answered that here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42278559/676195 IMO the interface is kind of confusing with tool tips intercepting the brush, but there you go.