# d3,dc.js composite brush chart tooltip not working

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

As I mentioned above in composite chart tool tip is not visible after redraw the graph in d3.js. Grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: add code snippet,  [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that would help addressing your issue.

Comment: Everything in SVG is layers. If there is a brush it will block the hover events from getting to the little dots. So those features aren’t compatible, although you’ll find workarounds if you search SO a little.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display data point on top of brush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42251090/display-data-point-on-top-of-brush)

Comment: It's working......Thank you